# Meteor 1.3 React SSR support

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router, server-side-rendering

I am using Meteor 1.3 with React and FlowRouter(the SSR version). I want to achieve SSR but when I import my routes file in my server's `main.js`, I get an error basically saying one of my npm packages is calling `window` and `window` does not exists on the server.

Is there a way for me to somehow be able bypass this issue while still using the package? The package in question is [Wallop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wallop)

Comment: I don't think there's any way you could make `window` available, since there is no DOM on the server. It's also doubtful whether it would work even if you patch the library, since it heavily relies on DOM features. I believe implementing the same functionality in React should really be simple and straightforward though.

Answer (score 0):

window will never exist on the server. on node, global is the window like container.

I think anyway referring directly to the window object is not a good idea.

I can link you to my github profile where i have made a demo app with meteor, react and SSR: https://github.com/LucaMele/meteor-react-ssr-app-demo

Comment: In this case, it was one of the packages I had imported that was referencing window. Because it was not my code, and fork to add support for SSR was not an option, I went ahead and built my own package